# customizing an alertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm customing my own dialogBox:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:hint="@string/pull"/>

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/tira_cable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The screen width is 700 and the image width is 600 but it is not shown correctly:

[image]

And the image is:

[image]

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `scaletype` ex: `scaleType="fitXY"`

```
<ImageView
android:src="@drawable/tira_cable"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/tira_cable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

probably the scaleType you need is `"centerCrop"`